# Haskell: Create a list of tuples from a tuple with a static element and a list

Tags: haskell

Need to create a list of tuples from a tuple with a static element and a list. Such as:

```
(Int, [String]) -> [(Int, String)]
```

Feel like this should be a simple `map` call but am having trouble actually getting it to output a tuple as `zip` would need a list input, not a constant.

Comment: `c (i,xs) = map (\v -> (i,v)) xs`

Comment: Also known as `sequence`.

Comment: your terminology "static element" and "constant" (as opposed to a list) makes little sense. you could use "single value", but even that's dubious as that single value could itself be a list, depending on context.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the most direct and easy to understand solution (you already seem to be acquainted with `map` anyway):

```hs
f :: (Int, [String]) -> [(Int, String)]
f (i, xs) = map (\x -> (i, x)) xs
```

(which also happens to be the desugared version of `[(i, x) | x < xs]`, which Landei proposed)

then

```hs
Prelude> f (3, ["a", "b", "c"])
[(3,"a"),(3,"b"),(3,"c")]
```

This solution uses pattern matching to "unpack" the tuple argument, so that the first tuple element is `i` and the second element is `xs`. It then does a simple `map` over the elements of `xs` to convert each element `x` to the tuple `(i, x)`, which I think is what you're after. Without pattern matching it would be slightly more verbose:

```hs
f pair = let i  = fst pair  -- get the FIRST element
             xs = snd pair  -- get the SECOND element
         in map (\x -> (i, x)) xs
```

---

**Furthermore:**

The algorithm is no way specific to `(Int, [String])`, so you can safely generalize the function by replacing `Int` and `String` with type parameters `a` and `b`:

```hs
f :: (a, [b]) -> [(a, b)]
f (i, xs) = map (\x -> (i, x)) xs
```

this way you can do

```hs
Prelude> f (True, [1.2, 2.3, 3.4])
[(True,1.2),(True,2.3),(True,3.4)]
```

and of course if you simply get rid of the type annotation altogether, the type `(a, [b]) -> [(a, b)]` is exactly the type that Haskell infers (only with different names):

```hs
Prelude> let f (i, xs) = map (\x -> (i, x)) xs
Prelude> :t f
f :: (t, [t1]) -> [(t, t1)]
```

---

**Bonus:** you can also shorten `\x -> (i, x)` to just `(i,)` using the `TupleSections` language extension:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

f :: (a, [b]) -> [(a, b)]
f (i, xs) = map (i,) xs
```

Also, as Ørjan Johansen has pointed out, the function `sequence` does indeed generalize this even further, but the mechanisms thereof are a bit beyond the scope.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, consider also `cycle`,

```
f i = zip (cycle [i])
```

Using `foldl`,

```
f i = foldl (\a v -> (i,v) : a ) []
```

Using a recursive function that illustrates how to divide the problem,

```
f :: Int -> [a] -> [(Int,a)]
f _ [] = []
f i (x:xs) = (i,x) : f i xs
```

Comment: no downvote but the first example relies on currying, which the OP might not be familiar with; the second example uses a fold where a simple `map` would do, and it uses a generally contraindicated type of fold, `foldl`, which is prone to space leaks; the third example uses recursion which is even more unnecessarily complicated than a fold, when compared to a simple `map`.

Comment: Why should we expect the user to not know about currying? In any case it is time to start learning it because it is crucial to understanding Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension would be quite intuitive and readable:

```
f (i,xs) = [(i,x) | x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the `Int` to always be the same, just feed `zip` with an infinite list. You can use `repeat` for that.

```
f i xs = zip (repeat i) xs
```

Comment: a trivial error but the type of your `f` does not unify with the type expected by the OP.